# Why should I define a method as another variable for integers but not for array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

The following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int first = 1;
    int second = 2;
    sum(first,second);
    System.out.println(sum);
}
public static int sum(int a, int b){
    int sum = a+b;
    return sum;
}}
```

will return error and I need to write

```
int x = sum(first,second);
System.out.println(sum);
```

and define that method as integer x and print x.

But for array,

```
public static ArrayList<String> removeLast(ArrayList<String> list) {
//code
return list;
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    //code
    removeLast(persons);    

    System.out.println(persons);
}
```

will print the returned value of array without defining as another array as the was with the previous one.

I am sorry if the question has already been asked as I couldn't find it. And I am just learning Java.

Comment: trying to clear confusion gets downvoted :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are passed by (value of) reference, therefore, any change that happens to the array inside the method, will actually change the array passed in to it. On the other hand ints are passed by value. Change an int inside a method, and it won't change the int passed into the method.

For this reason, the return statement in your array method is completely unnecessary. Your code will still change the array, even if you omit the return statement.

But there's another misconception that needs to be pointed out: when you sum two ints, you are creating a new value in memory, which exists as long as the method is executed. When the `sum` method is done, the `sum` int doesn't exist anymore. To retain its value, you need to return it from within the method, and assign it to a variable where you call the code.

Comment: I checked by removing the `return` in method for array but I got error. Can you help me?

Comment: If you have a method that looks like this: `public static void removeLast(ArrayList<String> list) {   list.remove(list.size()-1); }` and you call from `main` like so:  `removeLast(list);` and then `System.out.println(list);` you'll see your desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Because Java is pass by value, but the value of reference types (including arrays) is a reference to the `Object` (in this case, a `List`). You might use a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) and (in Java 8+) an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) to implement it like

```
public static int sum(int... arr) {
    return IntStream.of(arr).sum();
}
```

Then you can call `sum` with as many (or few) `int` arguments as you like.

Comment: Even using a variadic function, you'd still need to store the returned value in a variable.

Comment: `System.out.println(sum(1, 2, 3));`

Comment: well, that would work with the OP's code as well (although with two arguments only).

Answer (score 0):

> Will print the returned value of array without defining as another
>   array as the was with the previous one ?

Whatever @yeedle mentioned above is correct, but one point to add as below:

- **`ArrayList` class (actual type of `persons` object) has overridden the `toString()` method such that it
  could print the array details** when you invoke
  `System.out.println(persons);`.
- You need to know that for your objects (created for your custom
  classes like Product, Employee, etc..), you need to override
  `toString()` method (inherited from `java.lang.Object`) to print the
  values like how you wanted, otherwise simply using
  `System.out.println(object);` will print the `hashcode` of the
  object (like @HA5431 etc..).

You can look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

Comment: can you elaborate it? it is printing values correctly though.

Comment: Updated above, you can have a look